# Redirecionar para página de login ao acessar outra página sem usuário estar logado

Tags: demoiselle

Estou criando uma aplicação usando o framework demoiselle, mas estou encontrando alguns problemas com relação a parte de segurança.

Preciso que seja redirecionado automaticamente para a página login.jsf quando o usuário tentar acessar outra página da aplicação (index.jsf, empresa.jsf, etc) sem ter feito o login, ou seja, enquanto o usuário não realizar o login ele não terá acesso a nenhuma página.

Conforme documentação referente a versão 2.4.2 do demoiselle, o framework já dispoe desta funcionalidade conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme descrito acima, é necessário apenas informar a página de login e se deseja habilitar ou desabilitar o redirecionamento automático para a página de login após uma tentativa de acessar recurso protegido.

Pois bem, tentei realizar essa implementação mas não tive êxito, mesmo que tente acessar outra página sem que o usuário esteja logado, não é feito o redirecionamento para a página de login. Imagino que tenha implementado todas as classes necessárias para que o redirecionamento funcione. Abaixo segue como estão minhas classes e arquivos de configuração.

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.djsystem</groupId>
    <artifactId>DJCloud</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

**/WEB-INF/beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <class>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
        <class>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredPermissionInterceptor</class>
        <class>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.RequiredRoleInterceptor</class>
        <class>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.exception.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>

</beans>
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>#{messages['main.app.title']}</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>  
        <p:growl id="messages"/>
        <p:menubar style="font-weight: bold; font-size: small">
            <p:menuitem value="Portal DJCloud" url="#" />
            <f:facet name="options">
                <p:outputLabel for="login" value="Usuário: " />
                <p:inputText id="login" style="margin-right:10px" value="#{credenciais.username}" />
                <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha: " />
                <p:inputText id="senha" style="margin-right:10px" value="#{credenciais.password}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Login" icon="ui-icon-locked" action="#{securityContext.login()}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

**demoiselle.properties**

> frameworkdemoiselle.security.enabled=true
>   frameworkdemoiselle.security.authorizer.class=br.com.djsystem.djcloud.security.Autorizador
>   frameworkdemoiselle.security.authenticator.class=br.com.djsystem.djcloud.security.Autenticador
>   frameworkdemoiselle.security.login.page=/login.xhtml
>   frameworkdemoiselle.security.redirect.after.login=/index.xhtml
>   frameworkdemoiselle.security.redirect.after.logout=/login.xhtml
>   frameworkdemoiselle.security.redirect.enabled=true

**Autenticador.java**

```
package br.com.djsystem.djcloud.security;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.djsystem.djcloud.security.Credenciais;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.Authenticator;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.User;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Autenticador implements Authenticator {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Credenciais credenciais;

    @Inject
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    @Override
    public void authenticate() throws Exception {
        if (!credenciais.getUsername().equals("ricardo") || !credenciais.getPassword().equals("ricardo")) {
            throw new RuntimeException(bundle.getString("usuarioNaoAutenticado"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public User getUser() {
        return new User() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void setAttribute(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public String getId() {
                return credenciais.getUsername();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getAttribute(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void unauthenticate() throws Exception {
        credenciais.clear();
    }

}
```

**Autorizador.java**

```
package br.com.djsystem.djcloud.security;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.Authorizer;

public class Autorizador implements Authorizer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(String arg0, String arg1) throws Exception {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasRole(String arg0) throws Exception {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Credenciais.java**

```
package br.com.djsystem.djcloud.security;

import java.io.Serializable;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.ViewController;

@ViewController
public class Credenciais implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void clear() {
        this.username = null;
        this.password = null;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Caso seja necessário olhar o projeto inteiro, o link para download é este:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7z76co3usf1l6gv/Projeto_exemplo.7z?dl=0

Desde já agradeço possíveis ajudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As configurações estão corretas, mas as classes de autenticação, autorização e credenciais devem ser anotadas com @SessionScoped. 
Mas é preciso que esclarecer que o bloqueio é feito em recursos protegidos que podem ser classes, métodos, ou componentes de páginas. No exemplo que vc comentou, se o acesso for feito em uma páginas que não tem nenhum recurso protegido ela será apresentada. Pois podem haver partes da aplicação de acesso público
Abaixo alguns exemplo de melhorias que podem ser feita no código que vc passou:

Na classe Autenticador.java

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import br.com.djsystem.djcloud.security.Credenciais;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.AuthenticationException;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.Authenticator;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.User;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.util.ResourceBundle;

@SessionScoped
public class Autenticador implements Authenticator {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Credenciais credenciais;

    @Inject
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    private static boolean authenticated=false;

    @Override
    public void authenticate() throws Exception {
        if (!credenciais.getUsername().equals("ricardo") || !credenciais.getPassword().equals("ricardo")) {
        throw new AuthenticationException(bundle.getString("usuarioNaoAutenticado"));
    }else{
        authenticated = true;
    }
}

@Override
public User getUser() {
    if (authenticated) {
        return new User() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @OverrideA autenticação pode ter essa melhorias. podem ser melhoradas assim:
            public void setAttribute(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public String getId() {
                return credenciais.getUsername();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getAttribute(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }               
        };
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void unauthenticate() throws Exception {
    credenciais.clear();
    authenticated = false;
}

}
```

Você precisa implementar um ManagedBean para executar o login:

```
@ViewController
@NextView("./index.jsf")
public class LoginMB extends AbstractPageBean{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String usuario  = new String();
    private String senha = new String();

    @Inject
    private Credenciais credenciais;

    @Inject
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Inject
    private MessageContext messageContext;

    public String doLogin() {
        try {
            credenciais.setUsername(this.getUsuario());
            credenciais.setPassword(this.senha);
            securityContext.login();
            return getNextView();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            messageContext.add(e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }       
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void doLogout() {
        securityContext.logout();
    }
}
```

Sua página de login ficaria assim:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

   <h:head>
        <title>#{messages['main.app.title']}</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>  
            <p:growl id="messages"/>
            <p:menubar style="font-weight: bold; font-size: small">
            <p:menuitem value="Portal DJCloud" url="#" />
            <f:facet name="options">
                <p:outputLabel for="login" value="Usuário: " />
            <p:inputText id="login" style="margin-right:10px" value="#{loginMB.usuario}"  required="true"/>
                <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha: " />
                <h:inputSecret id="senha" value="#{loginMB.senha}" style="margin-right:10px"  required="true"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Login" icon="ui-icon-locked" action="#{loginMB.doLogin()}" />
           </f:facet>
    </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Você pode proteger o conteúdo "reservado" das páginas como por exemplo o menu:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:form >
        <p:menubar style="font-weight: bold; font-size: small"  rendered="#{securityContext.loggedIn}">
            <p:submenu label="#{messages['menu.bookmark']}">
                <p:menuitem value="#{messages['menu.menuitem.new']}"  url="/bookmark_edit.jsf" />
                <p:menuitem value="#{messages['menu.menuitem.list']}" url="/bookmark_list.jsf" />
            </p:submenu>

       <f:facet name="options">
            <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" placeholder="Procure"/>
            <p:commandButton url="http:/login.jsf" value="Logout" icon="ui-icon-extlink" action="#{securityContext.logout}" />
       </f:facet>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

E também proteger os métodos na classe de negócio:

```
@BusinessController
public class BookmarkBC extends DelegateCrud<Bookmark, Long, BookmarkDAO> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Override
    @RequiredPermission(resource = "bookmark", operation = "insert")
    public Bookmark insert(Bookmark bookmark) {
        return super.insert(bookmark);
    }

    @Override
    @RequiredPermission(resource = "bookmark", operation = "delete")
    public void delete(Long id) {
        super.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    @RequiredPermission(resource = "bookmark", operation = "delete")
    public void delete(List<Long> ids) {
        super.delete(ids);
    }

    @Override
    @RequiredPermission(resource = "bookmark", operation = "findAll")
    public List<Bookmark> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();  
    }

    @Override
    @RequiredPermission(resource = "bookmark", operation = "load")
    public Bookmark load(Long id) {
        return super.load(id);
    }

    @Override
    @RequiredPermission(resource = "bookmark", operation = "update")
    public Bookmark update(Bookmark bookmark) {
        return super.update(bookmark);
    }

}
```

Desta forma quando houver tentativa de acesso a alguma página que acesse algum método protegido, será direcionada para a página de login.