# Bookmark não redireciona para página de login

Tags: java, jsf, demoiselle

Segui o post sobre autenticacão e autorização no demoiselle mas não consigo redirecionar para a página de login, segue arquivos:

```
frameworkdemoiselle.security.enabled=true 
frameworkdemoiselle.security.authorizer.class=br.gov.serpro.bookmark.security.Autorizacao    
frameworkdemoiselle.security.authenticator.class=br.gov.serpro.bookmark.security.Autenticacao 
frameworkdemoiselle.security.login.page=/login.xhtml
frameworkdemoiselle.security.redirect.after.login=/index.xhtml
frameworkdemoiselle.security.redirect.after.logout=/login.xhtml
frameworkdemoiselle.security.redirect.enable=true
```

tela de login.xhtml

```
<h:head>
    <title>#{messages['main.app.title']}</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="messages" />
        <p:menubar style="font-weight: bold; font-size: small">
            <p:menuitem value="Portal Sistema" url="#" />
            <f:facet name="options">
                <p:outputLabel for="login" value="Usuário: " />
                <p:inputText id="login" style="margin-right:10px"
                    value="#{loginMB.usuario}" required="true"/>
                <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha: " />
                <p:inputText id="senha" style="margin-right:10px"
                    value="#{loginMB.senha}" required="true"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Login" icon="ui-icon-locked"
                    action="#{loginMB.doLogin()}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Alguma regra em  específico no web.xml? filtro?

Comment: Eu não entendo sobre isto, mas acredito que seja JSF? Adicionei as tags, por favor reverta a edição se eu estiver enganado.

Comment: esse tópico é o mesmo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54887/redirecionar-para-p%C3%A1gina-de-login-ao-acessar-outra-p%C3%A1gina-sem-usu%C3%A1rio-estar-loga

Comment: Segui esse tópico, e não funcionou...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique neste link [Aplicação de Exemplo](https://github.com/demoiselle/laboratory/tree/master/estacionamento) as configurações necessárias conforme a versão do Demoiselle que está usando.

Comment: Realmente não consigo fazer funcionar o redirecionamento para página de login, segui o exemplo do estacionamento e nada.  link para o projeto no github: https://github.com/WdCarrijo/bookmark

Comment: No seu projeto o arquivo index.html estava redirecionando para o outro index.xhtml quando deveria ser para login.xhtml. Havia também algumas outras correções. Para não ficar uma resposta extensa, fiz um pull-request na sua aplicação no GitHub, vendo as alterações você perceberá o que estava faltando. Mas caso tenha mais alguma dúvida é só perguntar por aqui.

Comment: Olá Emerson, fiz tudo que você tinha feito:

Comment: Faltou somente algumas coisas, do tipo, rendered, actionListener, não entendi ao certo, mas vou testar as alterações.

Comment: Obrigado à todos pela ajuda.